# HQL sub query in select statement

Tags: hibernate, subquery, hql

I am fairly new to nHibernate and HQL, however using the documentation I am sure it is possible to subquery within a select statement.

Attempting to execute this query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, (SELECT COUNT(accHld.ID) FROM AccountHolder accHld 
    WHERE a.ID = accHld.Account) FROM Account a GROUP BY a.ID
```

I receive is "HQL function expected before '(' in SELECT clause.".

I have tried adding the subquery in the group by function as well, to no avail. I was wondering if anyone knew what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need a subquery but left outer join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, COUNT(accHld.ID) 
FROM Account a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  AccountHolder accHld ON a.ID = accHld.Account
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the only problem is, that on top of the Account, I also need to join another class named "payments" as well as accountholders. The problem I have with this, is that they both map back to Accounts class, so i get duplicate information, even when using distinct. Would there be anyway around this?

Comment: I am not getting it, you want to join Account, Payments and AccountHolders to get which attributes of which table?

Comment: Sorry, okay so, I have 3 enities. Payments, Accountholders and Accounts. Payments and Accountholders both have a mapping to Account. Using HQL, left joining both using Account.ID and the foreign keys in both Payments and AccountHolders, and SELECTING data, returns dublicates.

Comment: In your models, does Payment and/or AccountHolder have an object type Account?

Comment: That is correct, both Payment and AccountHolder have the object type Account.

Comment: So, hql allows to do queries through objects so you can do: `SELECT accHld.id, accHld.account.id FROM package.AccountHolder accHld WHERE accHld.account.attribute = value`. This will return AccountHolder id and it's related Account id where the AccountHolder's related Account attribute1 is value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156086/discussion-between-kleo-g-and-aldeguer).